# debian libsane-common, dependencies, and canon LIDE-120

Tags: debian, canon-lide, sane

I'm running debian-stable (stretch).

I have a canon LIDE-120, a scanner which in debian seems to require libsane-common-1.0.27, which is currently available only in sid (debian-unstable).

So my scanner is currently not usable. I wonder whether that can be fixed in the short run, without too much disruption of my debian system.

I have to confess that I've installed *some* packages from unstable (e.g. guile-2.2.3), but only ones without a large number of dependencies.

The approach I *considered* in this case was via [including the unstable repository in my apt/sources and using "pinning"](https://www.binarytides.com/enable-testing-repo-debian/),
but I chickened out - there were a lot of dependencies and hence an install of this packaged promised to install *a lot* of additional packages. (And if my memory is correct, apt threatened to do things like delete various packages - or maybe "metapackages" - like gnome).

So I wonder: is there another approach? Or must I just wait for  this package to get into "stretch/backports" before I can use my scanner?

Thanks,
george

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option to install from source. In general, this would mean

- remove tha SANE packages from your system
- download the sources for the backend and the frontends
- do `make && sudo make install`

However, be careful with dependencies.

Comment: thanks. In the end I "solved" the problem by converting one of my machines to "unstable".  It has now been a wile since I thought carefully about it, but by my memory, it semed that an attempt to build the SANE packages could raise a fair amount of depency issues, so I got lazy...